# reading DB credentials from props file in lift scala

Tags: apache, scala, properties, jetty, lift

I am just started working with Scala and lift frame work. i am trying to connect my DB using normal JDBC. i wish to read my DB credentials from the default.props file. i tried the following code so far:
in my default.props file:

```
db.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/scalatest
db.user=root
db.password=
```

And in my boot.scala file i am trying to do the JDBC connection like this:

```
val filename = "/src/main/resources/props/default.props"
Props.whereToLook = () => ((filename, () => Full(new FileInputStream(filename))) :: Nil)

val DBDriver = Props.get("db.class").toString
val DBURL =  Props.get("db.url").toString
val DBUsrName =  Props.get("db.user").toString
val DBPass = Props.get("db.password").toString

Class.forName(DBDriver)
val conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,DBUsrName, DBPass)
```

but while running the server using container:start command, fileNotFoundException is showing. can anybody tel what i have to do here. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the line where you change `Props.whereToLook`. It should already be set to the right values. ([more info on the Lift wiki](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Properties))

A note: The contents of the `src/main/resources` folder will normally be added directly into your classpath at runtime. So the file `src/main/resources/props/default.props` should be available via a call to `someClassInYourProject.getResourceAsStream("/props/default.props")`. Don't try to refer to a file in your source directory at runtime, as it will only ever cause headaches later on.